Is the "u" in "conspicuous" often reduced to /jə/?
I'm doing some research on when we pronounce the letter "u" as /jə/ instead of /ju/. Here's the link to a discussion that I found.
In this discussion, the OP asked how the letter "u" in the following words is pronounced:
 document
circulation
simulation
formula
communication
argument
regulation
manipulation
To which many native speakers confirmed that they are often pronounced as /jə/, except for "communication" because the syllable "mu" in "communication" has the secondary stress.
But then I looked conspicuous up in CD and found that the syllable cu, despite not being stressed, is pronounced as /kju/.
Why is that so?

Is this US, UK, or somewhere else? The OED gives US /kənˈspɪkjəwəs/ (with syllable breaks presumably /kənˈspɪk.jə.wəs/), UK /kənˈspɪkjʊəs/; though Cambridge has /kənˈspɪk.ju.əs/ for both. I'm sure it often gets weakened even in UK pronunciation though; dictionaries don't necessarily record fast, unstressed, or weakened pronunciations.

Impossible to say 'why it is so'. Some people are more 'careful' speakers than others.

/jəwəs/  sounds regional to me. Sounds like Jerry Seinfeld's accent. The AmE speakers in my ambit pronounce the third syllable like "you" /ju/ but the syllable is brief.

It is the -uous ending that is involved here (vacuous, contiguous, contemptuous, voluptuous, impetuous, strenuous,incongruous, tenuous etc). Communication is not relevant.

We don't usually reduce the "u" in words that end with "uous" because you would have two consecutive schwa sounds, with no consonant between them. They would be merged and it would end up being pronounced like "con-spic-yus"

Also, the logic of the assumption you are making in your question is questionable: in syllables receiving a stress (primary or secondary) we find /ju/  ergo in syllables not receiving a stress we should not find /ju/.

In AmE dialects that reduce the first syllable of -uous- endings  to /jə/  the pronunciation is often  /jəwɪs/.   That second /ə/ becomes /ɪ/

@TimR "ergo in syllables not receiving a stress we should not find /ju/" => Which part made you think that I object to that?

"But then I looked conspicuous up in CD and found that the syllable cu, despite not being stressed, is pronounced as /kju/." [your emphasis]   I don't think you object to it; I think you mistakenly assume it to be true.

There is no secondary stress on the third syllable of conspicuous: it is a fully unstressed syllable, but vowels in fully unstressed syllables are not always reduced to the schwa sound.
In this case, a pronunciation with /ə/ is avoided because the -u- in conspicuous is followed by another vowel sound. A pronunciation like /kənˈspɪkjəəs/ would have a sequence of two /ə/ sounds in a row: while this is not absolutely banned, /ə/ tends not to be used befor another vowel sound in English words like this, where the first unstressed vowel letter is has an alternative pronunciation. Other vowel sounds that can be found before another vowel in fully unstressed syllables are /i/ (very often, as in various or calcium; sometimes a pronunciation with [i] + vowel alternates with a pronunciation with [j]) or /o/ (less common, but found in words such as heroine, shadowy, borrowing).
